# correct way to pass parameters in azure functions?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, arguments

I am trying to use azure functions to give input parameters such as file paths and user name, when the http trigger is made.
Everything seems to be running in local envrt when I pass parameters as :

http:localhost:7071/api/myfunction?file_paths=file1.txt,file2.txt&username=xyz

the code works the way I wanted it to. but when I deploy it in azure and I grab the url and pass the parameters like below

url?file_paths=file1.txt,file2.txt&username=xyz

this does not work. I get a 401 error. I tried looking into the access of storage accounts(I made "enabled from all networks")

and tried hardcoding the file paths and user name. It works.

So, I believe the problem is in the way I pass arguments.

Could someone pass any inputs/suggestions on what to take care of?

Comment: A `401` stands for unauthorized. So it sounds like you are running into a different issue. Is your function setup to allow anonymous access? Else it will expect you to pass a key through the `x-functions-key` header.

Comment: It does have anonymous access. I used logic to handle when no parameters are passed. and it gives me output the way I handled the logic. but only when I pass parameters it's giving me a 401 error. Within the logic, I am accessing azure storage accounts and even that is set as "enabled from all networks".  I handled parsing of file paths too. just in case if my file path has spaces..

Comment: How do you authorize with the storage account or are your containers setup for anonymous access? You have some code to show?

Comment: my bad. I had set my access as "function" and not "anonymous". The function app works. thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check what is defined in the function.json file:

```
{
    "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
    "bindings": [
        {
            "authLevel": "function",
            "type": "httpTrigger",
            "direction": "in",
            "name": "req",
            "methods": [
                "get",
                "post"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "http",
            "direction": "out",
            "name": "$return"
        }
    ]
}
```

in the above sample,  **"authLevel": "function",**, which means that in order to trigger the function, you need to provide the function key. You can grab it (or create a new one) from the portal:

[image]

You can also click over Functions, in the left menu, then get the Function URL (which will contain the Function Key appendend):

[image]